# Building Qt project to use on Symbian 3rd edition

Tags: qt, symbian

I have made this application in Qt Creator, and everything workd fine in simulator. The problem is when i want to publish my project to test it in an emulator or on Symbian device, I have only option to publish for Symbian Anna and no option for symbian 3rd edition... I would appreciate any help you can provide me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can build a sis file for S60v5. Not sure about S60v3, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Develope app for Symbian Anna as Selected Device then We can't publish app for 3rd edition.

Make Sure 3rd Edition SDK is added to Qt Creator and While Creating New Project then Select for 3rd Edition instead of Symbian Anna.

Because if you Develope app for 3rd Edition Mobiles they work in latest Mobiles like Symbian anna or bella. If you Select Higher version as Development SDK then they will not Work in Lower Versions.

Comment: Ya, Check this link for installation http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/requirements-symbian.html